# Visual Studio unhandled win32 exception occured in devenv.exe

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok I am new to programming, VB.net and Visual Studio. 
I have tried to create a small local database in VB.net using an Access file. Every time I add the dataset VS crash and I get this error

unhandled win32 exception occurred in devenv.exe

I have looked for answer on Stackoverflow and there is a few with the same problem but have tried their solutions and still no joy. Have already re-installed all VS to get rid of errors or bugs etc as per MSDN. Also checked and have the latest .NET framework installed as well.

Any other solutions please
It is Visual Studio 2010, and so is the MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solutions:

1. If we reboot the operating system to safe mode, do we have the problem? This can help to isolate whether any other applications are interfering with Visual Studio. Note that some features (like IIS) are not available under safe mode. Please check whether this can apply or not. In addition to safe mode, we can also suggest “clean boot”: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353.
2. If we create a new user account, do we have the problem? This can help to isolate user profile corruption related causes.
3. If we disable Add-ins (e.g. “Tools” | “Add-in Manager”) and run “devenv.exe /safemode”, do we still have the problem? This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins are causing problems.
4. If we use “devenv.exe /resetsettings”, does it solve the problem? It restores Visual Studio default settings.
5. If we create a new project, do we have the problem? Sometimes corrupted project settings can cause problems. These are project specific.
6. If the problem remains, we can use Visual Studio Setup Wizard (via Control Panel) to repair Visual Studio. It can restore the Visual Studio Installation into its original state.

Link to this above text : [An unhandled win32 exception occurred in devenv.exe[6048]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82b4b8c2-c18d-4bc4-9b5c-4cd9ded675f6/an-unhandled-win32-exception-occurred-in-devenvexe6048?forum=vssetup)

I had similar problem 4 months ago, and under 4 (devenv.exe /resetsettings) helped me.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. I have gone through the list and just about have done everything. Eventually found out that Norton is the one that caused it. As soon as I disabled it then all was good. Had to run it in safe mode to find that out.